# Why would adding a func in an interface cause json.Unmarshal to fail?

Tags: json, go

Why does this fail with the error :

> json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Person.spouse of type main.Spouse

```
type Spouse interface {
    Name() // Adding this causes an error
}

type Address interface {
}

type Person struct {
    Name string   `json:"name"`
    A    *Address `json:"address"`
    S    *Spouse  `json:"spouse"`
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{
     "name":"sarah", 
     "address":{
         "street":"101 main" 
         }, 
     "spouse":{
         "name":"joe"
         }
     }
    `)

    p := &Person{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, p); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
}
```

Looking at the [docs](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=4062:4110#L97), I don't see why adding a function in an interface would cause an error. I was expecting json.Unmarshal to simply ignore the *Name()* function since it's not part of the [list](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s=4062:4110#L54) processed by json.Unmarshal.

Here is the code in [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Hf2juE9yBy8).

go version go1.10 darwin/amd64

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://gregtrowbridge.com/golang-json-serialization-with-interfaces/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> **func Unmarshal**
>   [...]
>   To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> ```
> bool, for JSON booleans
> float64, for JSON numbers
> string, for JSON strings
> []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> nil for JSON null
> ```

You're trying to unmarshal a JSON object into an interface so the value behind that interface is going to be a `map[string]interface{}` to represent the key/value pairs. But `map[string]interface{}` doesn't have a `Name()` method so it doesn't implement your `Spouse` interface.

If we simplify your example a little and get rid of the `Name()` method we can see what's going on:

```
type Spouse interface {
}

type Person struct {
    S *Spouse `json:"spouse"`
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"spouse":{ "name":"joe" } }`)

    p := &Person{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, p); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    spouse := (*p.S).(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", spouse)
}
```

`spouse` is a `map[string]interface{}` as documented.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to map the value of `spouse` in the json with a particular data type that doesn't match. As reported in [this article](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go), json uses empty interface to map generic data types to the right one used in the file.

> The json package uses `map[string]interface{}` and `[]interface{}` values
>   to store arbitrary JSON objects and arrays; it will happily unmarshal
>   any valid JSON blob into a plain `interface{}` value. The default
>   concrete Go types are:
>
> - `bool` for JSON booleans,
> - `float64` for JSON numbers,
> - `string` for JSON strings, and
> - `nil` for JSON null.

If you want to see it from another perspective, it means that you can't use anything other than these data types to map data in JSON. And your **not empty** interface isn't a valid type.